# Load data infile ignore 1 lines skip 2 lines

Tags: mysql

I want to import a CSV file to my MySQL table using Load data infile, but sometimes it skips 2 lines.

My SQL:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\csv\\member.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE `member` 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (`UserName`, `RegDate`, `Address`, `Remark`);
```

Data:

```
"UserName","RegDate","Address","Remark"
"Peter",07-AUG-2001 18:17,"10th Floor, xxx's PlazaI","Remark xxx" xxx"
"Mary",07-NOV-2001 15:17,,"The ""BIG"" boss"
"Paul",07-DEC-2001 15:17,"10th Floor, xxx's PlazaI",""
```

Comment: How do you know it skip 2 lines?

Comment: After load data into table, check is it load correct number of data.

Comment: So, you're saying that when you check the table after `LOAD DATA ..`, the number of data is less (one row less), right?

Comment: yes, e.g. the csv total 4 lines, include first line is header, should be 3 row records in the table (after ignore 1 line for the header), but it only have 2 row records in the table

Comment: *but sometimes it skips 2 lines.* You use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. I predict that the delimiter between visual 1st and 2nd lines  is not `'\r\n'` (for example, it is `'\n'` only), and server assumes that these lines (lines which are printed on the screen like 2 separate lines) are not two lines but one solid line.

Comment: Maybe the excessive use of doyble quotation marks or even the single one, are preventing your data from uploading correctly. Load Data Infile is usually very sensitive.

Comment: After you run the query, run `show warnings`. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-show-warnings/